# Adding constraints to in image within scrollView breaks panning

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, zooming, nslayoutconstraint, pan

Using swift 3.0 iOS 10.x

Need an image within a scrollView to stick to the sides when I go from landscape to portrait and put this NSLayout rules into place.

```
        let imageViewRight = (NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.image2P, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
        let  imageViewLeft = (NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.image2P, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
        let  imageViewTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.image2P, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let  imageViewBot = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.image2P, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant:0)
        self.view.addConstraints([imageViewBot,imageViewTop,imageViewRight,imageViewLeft])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([imageViewBot,imageViewTop,imageViewRight,imageViewLeft])
```

They work, but of course if I zoom into the image I find they break panning.

I thought I might be able to get around it by activating and deactiving them, but even if I simply add them it breaks...  is this correct behaviour?